# Flutter Drift - parameters prohibited in CHECK constraints

Tags: flutter, sqlite, flutter-moor, drift, moor

I'm trying to use the [drift library](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/) (renamed from `moor`) ,but it's unable to create tables because of this error:

```
SqliteException(1): parameters prohibited in CHECK constraints, SQL logic error (code 1)
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS enterprise (name TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(LENGTH(name) <= ?), ..other fields);
```

This is the table class causing the error:

```
class Enterprise extends Table {

  TextColumn get name =>
      text().check(name.length.isSmallerOrEqualValue(maxNameLength))();

  // ...other fields
}
```

The error goes away if I remove the `check`. Could someone explain why the check isn't working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug with drift. This is the [workaround](https://github.com/simolus3/drift/discussions/1936) as suggested by the author of drift, and will be fixed in a future release.

Replace

```
check(name.length.isSmallerOrEqualValue(maxNameLength))
```

With this:

```
check(name.length.isSmallerOrEqual(Constant(maxNameLength)))
```